# Interface for Ionic angular 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, modal-dialog

Is it recommended to use interface in ionic 2?

Which means is it fine to use interface in ionic 2 or strictly we should not use it. My purpose of using interface in ionic2 is want to create a custom modal in my ionic application.

thanks
AK

Comment: Do you mean a typescript interface (something like this? `export interface myInterface`)?

Comment: yes, this kind of interface only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to not use TypeScript `interface` in your Ionic project.

It's a standard principle in TypeScript and the whole Ionic Framework is written in TypeScript. At the end it will be compiled to JavaScript anyways.

**Here are some resources**

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/what-is/#typescript